# Writing complex/nested JSON Writes in Scala PlayFramework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-json

Going to assume that I have two case classes: `Child`, `Parent` that look something like:

```
case class Child()
case class Parent(child: Child)
```

Assume I've already implemented `Writes[Child]`. I'd like to implement `Writes[Parent]`.

I'm able to do this using combinators:

```
implicit val parentWrites: Writes[Parent] = (
   (__ \ "child").write[Child]
)(unlift(Parent.unapply))
```

But with the following approach, the compiler complains that it's seeing the type `Child` while expecting a `JsValueWrapper`:

```
implicit val parentWrites = new Writes[Parent] {
   def writes(parent: Parent) = Json.obj(
      "child" -> parent.child
   )
}
```

Hoping someone can help me understand how to implement a `Writes[Parent]` without using combinators.

Comment: What is the structure of `Parent` and `Child`? Also what do you mean by "can't get it to work"? What is the error?

Comment: I've clarified the question as you've asked. The classes aren't interesting at all. I just haven't figured out how to write the `writes` function for `Writes[Parent]` correctly without using combinators.

Comment: Try wrapping `parent.child` with this: `Json.toJson(parent.child)`

Comment: Might be helpful: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaJson See: converting a Scala value the Json

Comment: It works for me without an empty `Child` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work for me without any compile issues.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Child(t: String)
case class Parent(child: Child)

implicit val parentWrites = new Writes[Parent] {
  def writes(parent: Parent) = Json.obj("child" -> parent.child)
}
```

If you are still having trouble, it would be useful if you can share your complete sample with stacktrace.

Comment: Yes this worked for me as well. It seems that IntelliJ is simply complaining to me about a JsValueWrapper.